# Docker: Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: php, docker

Im trying to reach http://localhost:8100 and all i get is: "Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8100"

In the src/ i have the docker file and a php folder in which i have both index.php and mysql.php files.
The docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
      MYSQL_USER: devuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: devpass
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"
  web:
    image: php:7.4.0-apache
    container_name: php_web
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./php/:/var/www/html/
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8100:80"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Commands on the terminal:

```
docker-compose up -d
docker exec -ti php_web sh
docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

When I try to reach localhost:8100/mysql.php it works fine but when i try to open either localhost:8100 or localhost:8100/index.php I get the error.

Any clues on what could be causing it? I hope Im being clear with my question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please share the output of `docker exec -ti php_web ls -la /var/www/html/`

Comment: I get: total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   70 Jul 11 23:06 ' index.php'
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  160 Jul 11 22:40  .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov 22  2019  ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  128 Jul 11 22:31  includes
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  118 Jul 11 22:43  mysql.php

Comment: So you get same issue like this link  http://ip172-18-0-58-bs558k5im9m000ech9m0-8100.direct.labs.play-with-docker.com/ ?

Comment: I get the 403 Forbidden error when trying to acces the index.php but for mysql.php works fine! (Im not being able to load the link you sent to me, idk why)

Comment: I am trying to reproduce your issue. The link must show the same issue that you described .. please try again :  http://ip172-18-0-58-bs558k5im9m000ech9m0-8100.direct.labs.play-with-docker.com/

Comment: Yes, now it showed for me! You are right, i get the same message

Comment: :) I answered your question ! check answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per output of `docker exec -ti php_web ls -la /var/www/html/`, i can see space in the name of the file :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 70 Jul 11 23:06 ' index.php'
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 160 Jul 11 22:40 . 
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov 22 2019 .. 
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 128 Jul 11 22:31 includes 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 118 Jul 11 22:43 mysql.php
```

rename it and remove the space

```
mv ' index.php' index.php
```

Comment: I found what was causing the issue!! It was a space just before the index.php!!! Omg! Many thanks!!

Comment: Great! so my first request for troubleshooting was valid.. I mean when I asked: "please share the output of `docker exec -ti php_web ls -la /var/www/html/`  – "